# Sticky menu - Fix to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a website, where the starting navbar is towards the middle of the first section.
However, I want to create something where, as you scroll through the first section, the navbar and title move up to the top, until it reaches the top, and then acts like a normal Title and navbar at the top (fixed positioning at the end, versus absolute positioning at the beginning).
Here is my HTML and CSS Code. Do I need javascript for this?
Thanks!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5b47dd31a9e028b8190b6ad4/1577742949961-Y1FS4223B1A76MMFL9JP/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kHH9S2ID7_bpupQnTdrPcoF7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z4YTzHvnKhyp6Da-NYroOW3ZGjoBKy3azqku80C789l0nQwvinDXPV4EYh2MRzm-RRB5rUELEv7EY2n0AZOrEupxpSyqbqKSgmzcCPWV5WMiQ/marc+show.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover fixed;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 63.5%;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  margin: 0 70px;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  transition: color 0.5s;
}

.navbar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8);
}

.Marc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 62.5%;
  left: 65px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.Marc a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.List {
  position: absolute;
  top: 63%;
  left: 29%;
}

.List ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}

.List ul li a {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#ABOUT">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#BOOKING">BOOKING</a></li>
      <li><a href="#MERCH">MERCH</a></li>
      <li><a href="#TICKETS">TICKETS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="Marc">
    <a href="#">MARC'S PAGE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="List">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com">youtube</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com">instagram</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com">twitter</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <section>
  </section>
  <section id="TICKETS">
    <h1>Tickets</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium odit quae, sequi sit ex numquam.</p>
  </section>
  <section id="MERCH">
    <h1>Merch</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium odit quae, sequi sit ex numquam.</p>
  </section>
  <section id="BOOKING">
    <h1>Booking</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium odit quae, sequi sit ex numquam.</p>
  </section>
  <section id="ABOUT">
    <h1>About</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium odit quae, sequi sit ex numquam.</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean something like a sticky navigation inside a container?

Answer (score 2):

Use **position sticky**

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
  border: 4px dashed #000;
}

.spacer {
  height: calc(50vh - 1em);
}


nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="spacer"></div>
<nav>NAVIGATION</nav>
```

Example with your code - a bit simplified

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

body {
  background: url(https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5b47dd31a9e028b8190b6ad4/1577742949961-Y1FS4223B1A76MMFL9JP/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kHH9S2ID7_bpupQnTdrPcoF7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z4YTzHvnKhyp6Da-NYroOW3ZGjoBKy3azqku80C789l0nQwvinDXPV4EYh2MRzm-RRB5rUELEv7EY2n0AZOrEupxpSyqbqKSgmzcCPWV5WMiQ/marc+show.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover fixed;
  font: 14px/1.4 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
   color: white;
   transition: 0.24s;
   text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

section#MENU {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  height: 60px;
}
section.MENU--pre {
  height: calc(65vh - 30px); /* 100vh - 60px, so use -30px */
}
section.MENU--post {
  height: calc(35vh - 30px); /* 100vh - 60px, so use -30px */
}

.Marc {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
.Navbar {
  padding: 0 30px;
}
.Navbar ul {
  display: flex;
}
.Navbar ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<section id="HOME" class="MENU--pre"></section>

<section id="MENU">
  <div class="Marc">
    <a href="#HOME">MARC</a>
  </div>
  <nav class="Navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#ABOUT">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#BOOKING">BOOKING</a></li>
      <li><a href="#MERCH">MERCH</a></li>
      <li><a href="#TICKETS">TICKETS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>

<section class="MENU--post"></section>

<section id="ABOUT">
  <h1>About</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium odit quae, sequi sit ex numquam.</p>
</section>

<section id="BOOKING">
  <h1>Booking</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium odit quae, sequi sit ex numquam.</p>
</section>

<section id="MERCH">
  <h1>Merch</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium odit quae, sequi sit ex numquam.</p>
</section>

<section id="TICKETS">
  <h1>Tickets</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium odit quae, sequi sit ex numquam.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: It's not that compatible yet https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky, perhaps a jQuery or some framework solution could work better till this gets official

Comment: @MihailMinkov I would not officially bother with IE11... 0.N% of IE11 users will simply see a navigation go away...

Comment: Thanks very much! Is there a better way to do it with javascript, by any chance? Because at first glance it seems this method just shifts the rest of the body down some, so my snap scroll align method doesn't work as well anymore... Thanks again!